# estimate of sum by integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am new here and i just want to made a proof of the following lemma with basic Analysis knowledge:

For $ p \geq 0$ and $ v \geq 2 $ : $$ \sum_{k=1}^{v} k\;^p < \int_0^{v+1} t^p \, dt $$

First I wanted to take of the maximum out of the sum, but then I have $v\;^{p+1} < \frac{1}{p+1} (v+1)\;^{p+1}$ and I do not know whether this is true or not. 
Is this the wrong way to proove the estimate?

It would be nice if someone can help me! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x^p$ is increasing, we know that $$k^p=k^p\cdot 1 <\int_k^{k+1}t^p dt$$ and the inequality follows.

Comment: I am sorry, but why do we exactly know that the inequality that you has posted is true?

Comment: Ahh ... i get it know, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)